# run xset command at startup

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xserver, xinput

I am running xubuntu 16.04.

I am running two commands at startup to configure my mouse.

Both work fine in the terminal.

When I set them to run at startup using the "Sessions and Startup" app, one takes effect and one doesn't.

The one that does take effect is an xinput command to change sensitivity.

The one that doesn't take effect is as follows....

```
xset m 2 12
```

Why won't this xset command work when I set it through "Sessions and Startup". The startup command is enabled and certainly configured properly.

Comment: What if you alter the command to `bash -c 'sleep 3 && xset m 2 12'` ? Does that take effect ?

Comment: This solved it, but I had to set it to sleep for 10 seconds. If you post your answer I will flag as the answer.

Comment: Will do so in about 20 minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it has been solved in the comments, the solution is to set the command to the command within a shell and delayed, like so:

```
bash -c 'sleep 10 && xset m 2 12'
```

The delays allows for GUI to properly start up, and then runs the specified command.

Comment: worked like a charm on ubuntu 19

Answer (score 0):

Write this to a text file

`#!/bin/bash (newline of code) code`
Make the file executable and start that on login.

Comment: that is exactly what I did do. "Sessions and Startup" is the startup applications app in Xubuntu.

Comment: OK, write this on a text file:

Comment: this approach did not work... I think the command is running fine, but for some reason xset is being set again afterwards or reset.

Comment: Well, sorry! (That I couldn't help)

Answer (score 0):

To turn on the back light leds for a keyboard,
I used this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c 'sleep 1 && xset led 3'
```

and then I launched the “*Startup Applications*” tool to set it to begin after login. Maybe for this command the delay isn't necessary.