# How do I run a command prompt every time my computer reboots?

Tags: command-line, mouse, gnome-terminal

I'm still a newbie to Linux and I have Ubuntu 18.04.

My problem is that my mouse is too slow. I've been searching the web and if I do:

```
xinput set-prop 12 146 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

the problem gets fixed. Until next reboot.

So how do I run this command every time I reboot?

I tried to get to root (whatever this mode is) by getting:

```
sudo -i
```

and then I typed:

```
@reboot xinput set-prop 12 146 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

But I got as a response:

```
Command '@reboot' not found
```

How do I run that command prompt every time my computer reboots?

Comment: Related: [run xset command at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874709/run-xset-command-at-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> command '@reboot' not found

That part is related to a cronjob. You edit cronjobs by typing `crontab -e` and can then add a time and date or a moment (like @reboot) on when to start a command. Don't use that for this kind of action: what you want is related to your session, user and desktop. Cron is intended for action that require no desktop, no interaction.

---

- Open a terminal
- type `cd Documents`
- type gedit `input.sh`. This open gedit with a new file named `input.sh`
- Insert:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash 
  xinput set-prop 12 146 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000`
  ```
- exit gedit and type `chmod 700 input.sh`
- You can test this by doing `./input.sh`. It should not show errors, probably show nothing at all.
- type `exit`  to close the terminal

Now find "startup applications"  in the menu, pick "add", give the new action a name and add the script you saved into the "command". Like thi (change rinzwind to your name):

[image]

And if done correctly this script gets started when you start a desktop session.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that USB device and property numbers are not the same from one boot to the next, depending on what devices are plugged in at that time. I've gotten around that by using the device NAME instead of number.  I have a similar shell script in startup applications, in which I use the following code:

```
# xinput set-prop 'USB Optical Mouse' 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 6
```

The device name + property name are likely different in your system. You can get them by running

```
xinput list-props 1
```

Replace '1' with the current device number of the device you want.