# Startup Application to increase mouse speed does not work (18.04.1)

Tags: mouse, startup

I want to run the following line of code at startup:

```
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 && xinput set-prop "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 289 0
```

It does not work. At the same time I have created a Startup Application to increase mouse wheel speed using imwheel which is working fine.

I've already tried adding a delay as explained in the following link but it is also not working
[run xset command at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874709/run-xset-command-at-startup)

When I run the command manually it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by creating a `50-mouse-speed.conf` file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` with the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Increase Logitech speed"
    MatchProduct    "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"
    Option      "TransformationMatrix"  "2.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.00"
    Option      "AccelerationProfile"   "-1"
    Option      "AccelerationScheme"    "none"
EndSection
```